# Laravel 5.3 sym link for storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How to create symlink for storage if that needs to be done through controller.

I tried Artisan::call('storage:link'); in my controller it creates a symlink in public folder for storage but gives an error "Can't change directory to storage: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

```
App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));
```

And don't forget to use **App** after namespace.

Another example like as to create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Of course, once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ['symlink()'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php):

```
symlink(public_path('images'), storage_path('images'));
```